# Blender 2.79 weird edge on design printed in 3D

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have the following design (it's the cover of a light wall switch). The design is basically a cube with a few boolean difference operations applied to it. I understand blender needs those edges. However those edges are printed on the first layer and that messes the print. I tried deleting them but that makes the face hollow. How can I erase those edges so that the print won't mess up?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Link to blender file:

[image]

Comment: I doubt many folks here will still have 2.79, but it looks as if you have double edges on those connecting lines from your image.  Single edges are still necessary as you say, but they shouldn't affect 3D printing.I think we'll need to see your Blend file to see what's going on. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it. We should still be able to open it in the latest Blender version (4.0.1).

Comment: @JohnEason I added the link to blender file download. I know this is an old version, it's the one I have access. At my job I have access to 3.6.4

Comment: Ok. It's night time here so I'll have a look at it tomorrow morning.

Comment: I don't have access to any 3D printing software here, but the built-in 3D-Print Toolbox addon in Blender 3.6.5 complains that the large faces on the upper and lower surfaces of the bottom of your 'tapa' object are non-flat faces. There doesn't appear to be any reason for that as far as I can see so I'm not sure what's going on there and am afraid I can't really offer any suggestions to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3D print add-on to identify if your model is correctly designed for 3D printing (3D-Print toolbox).

Comment: He doesn't have access to that in early Blender versions.